# Script doesn't work from cronjob

Tags: java, bash, cron

I have a java program that has to run over the DB to reindex the entries. This is a job that has to be done once a week.
I have written a script that executes the program:

```
var=$(which java)
nohup $var -Xmx2048m -jar javaProgram.jar $* -d javaProgramResource -re > /nfs/inf/app_storage/logs/service/service_refresh.log 2>&1 &
```

The reason I put the Java path in a variable is becouse I want it to be generic, we have Java installed on different locations on every environment.
By executing this script manually, it works perfect.

```
./reindex.sh
```

Now, I wanted to create a cron job that executes this script once a week (every saturday at 6 o'clock in the morning - the duration of this job is about 16 hours becouse there are a lot of entries in the DB).

```
0    6    *    *    6  cd /locattion/of/the/file; ./reindex.sh
```

Instead of getting the edited indexes in the log file (like when I start the script manually), I just get a message that says:

```
nohup: invalid option -- 'X'
Try `nohup --help' for more information
```

I guess it's a syntax error, but I'm not familiar with bash scripts and commands.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` in a statement before the `nohup` statement so the command you are executing is printed.

Comment: Presumably the issue is that `which java` is not returning anything. You should quote variable substitutions, so that an empty variable isn't treated as absent.

Comment: It's working when I call the script manually..

Comment: Replace `$var` by full path to java.

Comment: @Cyrus this would work, but only for one environment. My goal is not to edit the scripts on each environment, but them to get the java-path by themself.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call `which`; just running `nohup java -Xmx2048m ...` will cause the shell to go through the same path lookup that `which` uses.

Comment: @chepner I tried that, but then I get the message that 'java' is an unknown command..

Comment: @Lazar but you're missing chepner's point: if `which` can find `java`, `java` is already on the path, so you can just invoke `java`; if it's not on the path, `which` won't find `java`. So you may as well just execute `java`.

Comment: Replace `var=$(which java)` with a PATH variable with all possible paths to java and replace in next line `$var` by `java`.

Comment: You can not be generic this way in crontab script. When cron runs your script it does not inherit your environment settings. When you run it manually the which command finds java only because it is on your $PATH. But when cron runs it, its $PATH variable is may be empty or contains where basic entries.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I know that and it works fine with the java command, but only when I execute the script manually.. it still doesn't work from the crontab..

Comment: @BalázsNemes is there a way to set the $PATH variable so that the cronjob can find it/inherit it?

Comment: @LazarZoltan, I think what you set in `/etc/environment` will be available globally, even for crond, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
In the .profile file were all the variables needed in the script.
I simply added the path of the .profile file to the cronjob and it worked just fine.

```
0    6    *    *    6  . $HOME/.profile; cd /locattion/of/the/file; ./reindex.sh
```

Now the cronjob knows the Java-Path (becouse it's written in the .profile file) and the name of javaProgramResource, which is also different on every environment. 
You guys gave me some very important input in which direction I should continue my investigation on this topic. Thanks!